# "Parse new" gives runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: parse-platform

I installed the command line tool, and I try to ran the "New Parse":

[image]

And I have the three folders created "public & cloud & config" but code in main.js **not** loaded from cloud.

How I can solve problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in my case it was a problem with proxy. 
As I know there is no way to configure proxy and I need a direct connection to the Internet to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving similar errors and my cause was a syntax issue:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getEventMatches", function(request, response) {
    // code
}
```

It's missing the ); at the end. So my suggestion is to make sure the syntax is correct in your cloud code.